# read char from console

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I write console application which performs several scanf for int
And after it ,I performs getchar :

```
int x,y;
char c;
printf("x:\n");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("y:\n");
scanf("%d",&y);
c = getchar();
```

as a result of this I get `c = '\n'`,despite the  input is:

```
1
2
a
```

How this problem can be solved?

Comment: `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @unwind - "Returns the next character from the standard input (stdin)."-ascii for char

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because `scanf` leaves the newline you type in the input stream. Try

```
do
    c = getchar();
while (isspace(c));
```

instead of

```
c = getchar();
```

Answer (score 3):

Call `fflush(stdin);` after `scanf` to discard any unnecessary chars (like \r \n) from input buffer that were left by `scanf`.

Edit: As guys in comments mentioned `fflush` solution could have portability issue, so here is my second proposal. Do not use `scanf` at all and do this work using combination of `fgets` and `sscanf`. This is much safer and simpler approach, because allow handling wrong input situations.

```
int x,y;
char c;
char buffer[80];

printf("x:\n");
if (NULL == fgets(buffer, 80, stdin) || 1 != sscanf(buffer, "%d", &x))
{
    printf("wrong input");
}
printf("y:\n");
if (NULL == fgets(buffer, 80, stdin) || 1 != sscanf(buffer, "%d", &y))
{
    printf("wrong input");
}
c = getchar();
```

Comment: -1 `fflush(stdin)` is not defined. Even [Microsoft/MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (who defines such a construct) says (albeit in a hidden location) it is an extension: "// fflush on input stream is an extension to the C standard".

Comment: @pmg: True! (Even I tend to point it out time to time). This comes up quite a bit on SO., but it *works* MSDN supports (you have linked the page) and so does [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush)... `"For input streams, fflush() discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application...The standards do not specify the behavior for input streams. Most other implementations behave the same as Linux. "`...so how bad is it to use in the code?

Comment: The text at the [POSIX.1-2008 page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fflush.html) is slightly different: it doesn't mention the application at all. I don't like that POSIX.1-2008 description at all. Linux and Windows and POSIX (with all the caveats) are not enough for me to call portable.

Comment: @another.anon.coward: also why would you willingly limit yourself to Linux and Windows and POSIX (with all the caveats) when you can very very easily reach much more implementations?

Comment: @pmg: You are definitely right about portability! But if I were to restrict this call in my implementation on platform which support say Linux I could very well use this with macro like `#ifdef LINUX` (maybe something like using C extensions of say gcc when possible). As you have mentioned it is better to stick with the standards. Thanks for your insights!

Comment: revoked the -1 ... even Yoda condition with ... and why is there a `c = getchar();` in your code?

Comment: @pmg so what is the correct cross platform way to discard all unnecessary characters left after scanf or gets?

Comment: @Romeno: the correct cross platform way to read user input is with `fgets()`. `fgets()` leaves no unnecessary characters left in the input stream.

Comment: @pmg well, thats not true. MSVC10 `fgets()` do leaves unnecesseary characters in the input stream. Moreover it does not return NULL if you entered more than `n-1` characters. It just clamps the input stream to `n-1`. Next `fgets` will continue to consume the entered characters.

Answer (score 3):

A way to clean up anyspace before your desired char and just ignore the remaining chars is

```
do {
    c = getchar();
} while (isspace(c));
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fflush function to clear anything left in buffer as a consquence of previous comand line inputs:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` invokes Undefined Behavior as per the C standard although it is well-defined on some systems (implementations) but it is best to avoid it in order to improve portability.

Answer (score 2):

For a start the `scanf` should read `scanf("%d\n", &x);` or y. That should do the trick.

[man scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: It doesn`t work :after I enter 1 it doesn`t write "y:"(see the updated example),but waits for the second number and only after it writes "y:"