# Yes/no does not work

Tags: c

```
do {
        p++;
        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf("%s", &string);
        fprintf(fw, "%d\n%s\n",p, string);
        printf("Enter your telephone number: ");
        scanf("%d",&cislo);
        fprintf(fw, "%d\n",cislo);
        printf("If u want to add more datas press Y otherwise press N ");
        c = getchar();
        while (getchar() != '\n')
            ;
        if ( c == 'Y')
            k++;
        else
            printf("You decided not to continue.");
    } while (p < k);
```

Hello the end of the code seems not to work becuase when i enter Y it shows "You decided not to continue" which is bullshit coz it should increase k by 1 and go one more time(p nad k are declared at the beginning of the program ,p = 0; k = 1; Could you tell me the solution please ?

Comment: are you sure that you typed 'Y' not 'y' ?! Change your condition and check for a lower 'y'.

Comment: Maybe you will need something like this: `if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y') {...}`. In addition `c` should be an `int`.

Comment: yes im sure i typed Y i even tried to put there c == 'y'  and type y  but it was the same.   EDIT : the while loop with ; before is because after i press y theres gonna be pressed enter

Comment: possible duplicate of [read char from console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853154/read-char-from-console)

Comment: And you of course removed the new line left after previous scanf, right? Also you of couse tried to debug your code by printing out what actually your variable c holds.

Comment: @zubergu after c = getchar();  i wrote putchar(c); and when i started the code again and wrote y it should show me y in console but it actually didnt it seems like theres nothing in c but  i dont know why so maybe thats the reason why it doenst work, btw yeah c is declared as int

Comment: @paxie not nothing, there's new line. print c as integer, see what ascii character this decimal value corresponds to.

Comment: @zubergu - don't be silly - doing all your debugging is what SO is for :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should empty the `stdin` buffer before read something else.

```
void emptyBuffer() {
    char c = 'a';
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        c = getchar();
    }

    return;
}
```

This function empty the stdin buffer.

```
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &string);
    emptyBuffer();

    fprintf(fw, "%d\n%s\n",p, string);
    printf("Enter your telephone number: ");
    scanf("%d",&cislo);
    emptyBuffer();

    fprintf(fw, "%d\n",cislo);
    printf("If u want to add more datas press Y otherwise press N ");
    c = getchar();
```

Because when you use `getchar()`, you probably get the last `'\n'` of the previous question (/answer).

And BTW (according to previous comments)
you should use:

```
   if ( c == 'Y' || c == 'y' )
```

which is more user friendly :)

Comment: Thanks you a lot its working but could u please tell me why i call that function before c = getchar(); and not after in the code?

Comment: Let suppose that the user respond : 
name : kaldoran\n (\n due to enter)
scanf will get "kaldoran"
then number : 000000\n (enter again)
scanf will get "000000"
Bu stdin contains "\n" again, so you need to remove that "\n".
That's why we empty the stdin buffer, to remove all garbage caracter

Comment: could you please accept the answer if this one work :D thx

Comment: Yes sorry now i understand thank you a lot i forgot to accept it before :D sorry now i did it

Answer (score 0):

With your `c = getchar();` you are reading the `'\n'` (return) of telephone number input.

To avoid it you must flush `stdin` or, in this case, call `getchar()` twice.

Another simple way is to use scanf to do the work:

```
scanf("%s", c);
if (( c[0] == 'y') || ( c[0] == 'Y'))
   k++;
```

**EDIT**

As asked by OP, a complete solution could be:

```
do
{
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &string);
    fprintf(fw, "%d\n%s\n",p, string);

    printf("Enter your telephone number: ");
    scanf("%d",&cislo);
    fprintf(fw, "%d\n",cislo);

    printf("If u want to add more datas press Y otherwise press N: ");
    scanf("%s", c);

} while (( c[0] == 'y') || ( c[0] == 'Y'));

printf("You decided not to continue.\n");
```

Comment: thank you for your response as well it works this way too EDIT: no it works coz i declared p = 0 and k = 1 so 1st time it increases p to 1 if i press n its 1<1 which is false so it ends but if i press y it increases k from 1 to 2 so 1<2 which is true so it repeats , p to 2 then again if i press y k goes to 3 2<3 so it repeats again  maybe for you :D its kind of stupid but i have been learning C for like 3 days you know

Comment: You're welcome sir. Remenber to change the while condition..

Comment: check my previous post i explained the  do while loop

Comment: Ok. I edited. I saw both to 0.

Comment: anyways as i said maybe its stupid and theres much  "smarter" way if u have better solution could you please write it?

Comment: I Edited. Take a look.

Comment: Note that your now overwriting `string` and `cislo` every time. (You should save them in an array).

Comment: @moffeltje I modified OP code. Original is writing data to file. BTW I edited.