# What is the getchar() used for in this c code?

Tags: c, getchar

```
struct   Empregado  v_empregados[10];

main() {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf  (“Nome  e  apelidos?  “);
        gets  (v_empregados[i].nome);

        printf  (“Idade?  “);
        scanf(“%d”,&v_empregados[i].idade);
        getchar();

        printf(“Domicilio?  “);
        gets  (v_empregados[i].domicilio);

        printf  (“Salario?  “);
        scanf(“%f”,&v_empregados[i].salario);
        getchar();
}
```

In this code what is the purpose of using getchar()?

Comment: Because http://stackoverflow.com/a/8853198/2564301

Comment: Is used to get blank spaces?

Comment: The code is outside the `main()` function, so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well, it does something: it refuses to compile. OP, please make sure you're posting correct and properly indented code the next time.

Answer (score 2):

**This is broken code.**

The programmer uses that `getchar()` to clear the unread newline from the input buffer after the previous `*scanf()`. It's a common pattern.

Note that if the next input is `*scanf( "%d" )` or `*scanf( "%f" )` or really any `*scanf()` beginning with a conversion other than `%c`, `%[` and `%n`, leading whitespace will be skipped anyway, which would make the `getchar()` redundant.

But more importantly:

**Don't use `gets()`, ever.** There is **no way** this function can be protected against buffer overflow, and it has been **removed** from newer versions of the language standard for exactly that reason. **Use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.**

Secondly:

**If** you are using `*scanf()` to read user input (1), **at least check the return value**. If the user entered something that didn't match expectations, input matching will have failed, leaving the arguments (e.g. `v_empregados[i].nome`) *uninitialized*.

---

(1) `*scanf()` is good when reading back formatted data that has been written previously by your own application. But if there is any chance that the input might *not* be in the expected format (like when asking the user for input), the abilities to recover gracefully from that condition are limited. The general advice here is to use `fgets()` to read a full line of input, and then parse that in-memory using e.g. [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) or [`strtod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof), which are superior in many ways. You can also go back and try a different parsing as often as you like.

Answer (score 0):

The `getchar()` is added in order to discard the `\n`(newline character) left over by the previous `scanf()` (Remember pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering a number for the `scanf`?).

Without the `getchar()`s, the `\n` will be left in the `stdin` and once the execution reaches `gets`, it sees the newline character in the `stdin`, consumes it, and thus, does not wait for further input.

Answer (score -1):

It is done to consume the left out newline character `\n` after the previous `scanf()` gets executed.

This issue can also be solved by adding a space to the next `scanf()`, like in your code..

```
scanf(“ %d”,&v_empregados[i].idade);
```

**NOTE**

> Don't use `gets()`, it has been deprecated.

*However, most of your code is outside the `main()` function, so it won't get compiled.*

Comment: In is case it does nothing though since its called outside of the `main()` and not in a function.

Comment: @Magisch Thats not relevant i guess, its a small error.. However i will include that in the answer.

Comment: @Haris I agree, but it should be mentioned.

Comment: `It is done to consume the left out newline character \n` - this is not correct, you don't need to do this if you're using `%d`, `%f` etc.

Comment: @Michi yes, thats wat i meant.

Comment: "_most of your code is outside the `main()` function, so it won't get executed_" -- It won't even get compiled!

Comment: "_This issue can also be solved by adding a space to the next `scanf()`_" -- That `scanf` will behave the same with or without the space.

Comment: @CoolGuy, i guess m mixing things up here, Does this solves problems only for `char` inputs.

Comment: @Haris What? Could you explain?

Comment: @CoolGuy *Note that if the next input is *scanf( "%d" ) or *scanf( "%f" ) or really any *scanf() beginning with a conversion other than %c, %[ and %n, leading whitespace will be skipped anyway, which would make the getchar() redundant.* Taken from an answer above. This i didn't know.